# Use of std::ostream for Printing Vectors

Tags: c++, vector, ostream

I'm quite new to C++ and I am trying to print out a vector of Institutions, which is a type of object that I created. The creation of the object and the rest of my program runs just fine but when I try to print out the vector, the "<<" gives an error that says "operand types are std::ostream".

```
void PrintVector(const vector<Institution> &institutions)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < institutions.size; x++)
    {
        cout << institutions.at(x) << endl;
    }
}
```

I've tried to do research on what std::ostream is or what it does but since I don't know a lot about C++ (or programming in general), I can't understand any of the sites that explain it. Why won't the usual "cout <<" work in this situation? Can anybody explain to me what this means or if there is a different way to print out my vector that doesn't require this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you written an `operator <<` for your `Institution` class?

Comment: Since you know that the values of `x` are valid indices into the vector, there's no point in checking them again with `institutions.at(X)`. Just use `institutions[x]`. Even better, read about iterators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to overload the ostream operator (<<) for your class Institution:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Institution& inst)
{
    os << inst.foo; /* some member variable */;
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so where it says inst.foo, am I supposed to put one of the members in the inst object?

Comment: @LiliaO.Yes, you would put all the members you wish to print

Comment: @Tas If I wanted to print multiple members, would I do it like this? `os << inst.x << inst.y << inst.z;`

Comment: @LiliaO. Yes that's correct, and you can format it as you wish (having newlines etc in between, or even by "The institution's name is " << inst.name )

Comment: @LiliaO. Tas is correct. You can do all sort of fancy printing using the stream operator. os << "x=" << inst.x << ", y=" << inst.y;  etc.

Comment: @Tas  @Mr_Pouet My members are private and when I do `os << inst.GetName();` (which is a function that I have used previously to access the private member variable "name") it comes up with an error. Is there something else that I should write instead?

Comment: @LiliaO. you need to make the `operator <<` a `friend` of `Institution` or provide `public` getters.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a C++ `ostream` (which `cout` is) does not have any way to print out an `Institution` object. You are going to have to overload the `operator<<` function in our `Institution` as described in the link posted in the other answer (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in order to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide an `operator <<` for your class:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Institution& institution)
{
    os << institution.getValue();
    // ...
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`operator<<` is overloaded to allow outputting built-in types like `int` and `double`.  But you'll need to tell the compiler how to output your class `Institution` by overloading it again:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Institution& inst) {
    os << inst.name(); // or something
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Man the competition is tough T.T

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems with the code that you have shown.

1)

```
for (int x = 0; x < institutions.size; x++)
```

std::vector::size() is a class method, a function. It is not a class member. This should read:

```
for (int x = 0; x < institutions.size(); x++)
```

2)

```
cout << institutions.at(x) << endl;
```

Unfortunately, `std::ostream` knows nothing about your `Institution` class. You will need to implement a class method, such as `display()`, that will assemble a printable representation of the contents of the class, and write it to the output stream. So, for example, if the class contains two `std::string`s, called `name`, and `address`:

```
class Institution {

// ...

public:

      void display(std::ostream &o)
      {
           o << name << std::endl << address << std::endl;
      }
// ...
};
```

... or, in whatever formatting style you want your class instances to be displayed. Then:

```
for (int x = 0; x < institutions.size(); x++)
     institutions.at(x).display(std::cout);
```

3)

Well, here's a bonus problem with your code. It is actually written in an obsolete C++ dialect that went out of style decades ago. Whatever textbook you're using to learn C++, you need to ditch it, and pick up a textbook that was written this century, and which will teach you modern C++. In modern C++, this becomes a much more readable:

```
for (const auto &institution:institutions)
     institution.display(std::cout);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are all correct. I will provide a slightly different answer to the displaying issue, as this is a recurring problem. What you can do is define an abstract class, we'll call it `IDisplay`, which declares a pure virtual function `std::ostream& display(std::ostream&) const` and declares `operator<<` as a friend. Then every class that you want to be display-able must inherit from `IDisplay` and consequently implement the `display` member function. This approach reuses the code and is pretty elegant. Example below:

```
#include <iostream>

class IDisplay
{
private:
    /**
    * \brief Must be overridden by all derived classes
    *
    * The actual stream extraction processing is performed by the overriden
    * member function in the derived class. This function is automatically
    * invoked by friend inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,
    * const IDisplay& rhs).
    */
    virtual std::ostream& display(std::ostream& os) const = 0;

public:
    /**
    * \brief Default virtual destructor
    */
    virtual ~IDisplay() = default;

    /**
    * \brief Overloads the extraction operator
    *
    * Delegates the work to the virtual function IDisplay::display()
    */
    friend inline
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const IDisplay& rhs)
    {
        return rhs.display(os);
    }
}; /* class IDisplay */

class Foo: public IDisplay
{
public:
    std::ostream& display(std::ostream& os) const override 
    {
        return os << "Foo";
    }
};

class Bar: public IDisplay
{
public:
    std::ostream& display(std::ostream& os) const override 
    {
        return os << "Bar";
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
    std::cout << foo << " " << bar;    
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21c980a12426aa91)